# Migrating two svn paths to a new single git repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to plan a migration from SVN to git to be done this weekend, and am struggling on migrating all of our history.

Our code is currently in SVN as http://server/svn/repos/projectName/trunk/

I'm able to get most of what we want doing the following:

```
git svn init http://server/svn/repos/projectName/trunk/ --no-metadata
git config svn.authorsfile users.txt
git svn fetch
```

We are permanently migrating to git and don't have references to any revision numbers yet, hence --no-metadata, also we don't care about migrating branches either.

This works for the most part, however our project was originally in http://server/svn/repos/trunk/oldProjectName

The repository contains several other projects and we are only interested in migrating one.
Is there a way to create new git repository that contains the commits from http://server/svn/repos/trunk/oldProjectName followed by http://server/svn/repos/projectName/trunk/ ?

I'm aware this won't work, but it demonstrates what I would like to achieve:

```
git svn init http://server/svn/repos/trunk/oldProjectName
git config svn.authorsfile users.txt
git svn fetch
git svn init http://server/svn/repos/trunk/oldProjectName
git svn fetch
```

I believe the answer lies in manually creating two remotes, one for the old svn path and one for the new svn path. I'm managed to get this far, and think the next step involves something along the lines of rebasing one on the other?

(Although I'm on windows, I'm still able - and comfortable - to use bash if required)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the `git svn` part of the problem; from what you've said it's not clear to me if you've managed to get the commits into a single repo and just need to get the histories stitched together, or are still working on getting them into a single repo in the first place.

**Getting the commits in a single repo**

There may be a more efficient approach (again, I don't really know `git svn`), but worst case you could import the second svn repo into a second git repo, then set the 2nd git repo as a remote on the first:

```
git remote add oldproject ../oldproject
git fetch
```

Then you should have

```
A --- B --- C <--(master)

X --- Y --- Z <--(oldproject/master)
```

**Stitching together the history**

Most likely you *don't* want to rebase.  `A` has no parent but contains a complete tree, which means git regards `A` as having created every file.  It also regards `X` through `Z` as having created all the files in a complete tree, so if you rebase them together you'll either get constant conflicts (if the directory structures match) or duplicate copies of all the files (if the directory structures don't match).

Instead you should probably re-parent with `filter-branch`.  You may want to read through the `git filter-branch` docs, but the simple example they give for this type of operation is

```
echo "$commit-id $graft-id" >> .git/info/grafts
git filter-branch $graft-id..HEAD
```

Keep in mind, in selecting `$graft-id` (the root commit of the "recent" history) and `$commit-id` (the head commit of the "old" history) that if the histories overlap, you probably want to adjust accordingly.  For example if you have

```
D' --- E' --- F --- G --- H <--(master)

A --- B --- C --- D --- E <--(oldproject/master)
```

then you would either use `F` as the graft ID (and `E` as the commit ID), *or* use `D'` as the graft ID (and `C` as the commit ID).

Answer (score -3):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)